# How to persist from build programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, persistence, settings

I want to be able to load some information programmatically into `Properties.Settings.Default` before I publish it, but it doesn't persist. How do I overcome that?

I have (as a test):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 = "abc";
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1;
}
```

I clicked on button1, then published (with clickonce) and then run the published application and clicked on button2. The `Text` was empty.

If don't publish the application, rather just close it and reopen it and click on button2 – I get "abc".

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ddeaca86-a093-4997-82c9-01bc0c630138/

Comment: @ctescu Thanks for the idea. But it (-adding `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();`) doesn't help.

Comment: @ctescu As I said, that doesn't help. Perhaps because this is a different scenario. I want settings from _before_ publishing to persist. In fact, I intend to load the settings programmatically, remove the code that loads it, and only then publish. (Though for now, even without the code removal it doesn't work.)

Comment: You don't need any code to do that. Just add it as a string reource and build???

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thanks. But as I stated in the question, that's just a test. The real object is something more complicated which I don't know how to add through the VS Settings dialog. Or perhaps you're referring to some other way to add resources? How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that the scope was "user". But if the scope is "application" – it can't be changed programmatically.

So there seems not to be a way to do it. Persist from build programmatically, that is.

Answer (score 1):

See the following post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C

Answer (score 1):

publishing won't click the button for you.

You need to detect the setting isn't initialised correctly (compare with an application setting perhaps) and then set and save it yourself.

Blank / doesn't exist / = somesettingToUpgrade

and a little routine to find a setting by name, set and save then you could put that in the button click handler as well as say FormLoad.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need publishing to click it. I click before publishing. And the setting is saved – since when I just close the program and start it again – clicking on button2 produces "abc". And I added `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();` to `button2_Click` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Select Project Properties. Select the resources tab. Select string resource in the drop down. Give it a name and a value. It will be in the default name space on the project and in code you can access it with Properties.Resources.ResourceName. Where resourceName is whatever you called it. You can put Files and Images in there as well, they all get compiled into the exe or dll.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to do it programmatically. I can't add a large array through that Visual Studio Dialog. Although I can add it as a file. But it would be better if I can just add it programmatically somehow. Hence the title of my question. (+1 for the effort, though.)

Comment: Okay rewind. What exactly are you trying to do? Resources are for fixed values like message strings,splash bitmaps and stuff . Settings are for in user persistence like remembering what folder you like to save stuff in, colour choices, column order in a  grid and such. I'm sure theres way of solving your problem, you will have to tell me what is though, as opposed to having me look at why your solution to some unknown isn't having it.