# How to add something complicated as a Resource or a Setting to a program?

Tags: c#, resources, persistence, settings

If I want to add a string as a setting or an image as a resource – I do it through Visual Studio.

But how do I add something complicated such as a large array or a Form which has to first be computed at runtime (or in case of the Form – populated with controls)?

I thought I could run it and persist it in settings (Properties.Settings.Default.Setting1 =...), and then publish. But that doesn't work (See: [How to persist from build programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302772/how-to-persist-from-build-programmatically) ).

So how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read up on [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? I know that's kind of a generic answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But actually that's how I've been doing things until now – serializing them to files. But it seems Resource files and Settings would be better.

Comment: The answer seems to be to serialize it to file and then add that file as a Resource (by clicking on "Resources" in solution explorer). And then read it: `byte[] MyResource = Properties.Resources.MyResourceFile;`

Answer (score 0):

As for a large array, you need to come up with an approach or mechanism for storing the data.

If it's a simple array that won't change very often, you can store it in the app.config.

If it's a datasource (ie: the data changes often) you could use an XML file and ideally a database.

I'm not really sure what you mean by persisting a Form. A Form should contain all controls compiled within it's own executable or dll. If you are asking how to populate the form, you would do this in the Main() method of the main form.